# column "l.Session_Device" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

My Query is.

```
SELECT t."Ad_ID", t."Ad_Binary", count(j.*) as cnt, l."Session_Device" FROM robot__ads t
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT o."adIDAdID", o."sessionIDId" FROM robot__session__scraper__data o) j 
             ON j."adIDAdID" = t."Ad_ID"
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT i."id", i."Session_Device" FROM robot__session_data i) l
             ON l."id" = j."sessionIDId"
 GROUP BY t."Ad_ID"
 ORDER BY t."Ad_ID";
```

Throws an error

```
ERROR:  column "l.Session_Device" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...LECT t."Ad_ID", t."Ad_Binary", count(j.*) as cnt, l."Session...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 53
```

If I will add the GROUP BY as per error it will not give the results I wanted. It Will not give the rows with group by of t."Ad_ID".

Comment: You should specify the expected result - if you want to have one row per ad_ID you need some kind of aggregation on the session_device column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` (or functionally dependent).  Perhaps you want those values in an array:

```
SELECT r."Ad_ID", r."Ad_Binary", count(o."adIDAdID") as cnt,
       ARRAY_AGG(sd."Session_Device")
FROM robot__ads r LEFT JOIN
     ON o."adIDAdID" = t."Ad_ID" LEFT JOIN
     robot__session_data sd
     ON sd."id" = o."sessionIDId"
GROUP BY r."Ad_ID"
ORDER BY r."Ad_ID";
```

Notes:

- The subqueries are utterly unnecessary.
- Use meaningful table aliases, rather than arbitrary letter.
- Don't put column and table names in double quotes.  That just makes queries harder to read, write, and maintain.